# No SDK manager in Android Studio Mac

Tags: android-studio

Where is the SDK manager on the mac version of Android Studio? I know under windows its under "Tools." I checked all the menus and I can't find it.

[image]

EDIT:

Looks like the buttons on the toolbar are greyed out as well:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some time has passed but I believe the solution to my problem was to make sure ANDROID_HOME was pointing to the right sdk location

Answer (score -1):

It should be under tools then Android tab. Try re installing your SDK and android studio.

Answer (score -1):

It's here in android studio 3.0 on my mac

[image]